# asp.net textbox not returning value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a master page the code is below

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="Admin.master.vb" Inherits="Admin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html >

<html >
<head runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_1.ico" />

        <title>Bright Coaching Centre</title>

        <!-- Base Css Files -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Font Icons -->
        <link href="assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/ionicon/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- animate css -->
        <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Waves-effect -->
        <link href="css/waves-effect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Custom Files -->
        <link href="css/helper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Plugins css-->
        <link href="assets/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/toggles/toggles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/timepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/colorpicker/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/jquery-multi-select/multi-select.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="assets/select2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    </head>
    <body class="fixed-left" >
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
            <div>
                <!-- Top Bar Start -->
                <div class="topbar">
                <!-- LOGO -->
                <div class="topbar-left">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a class="logo"><i class="md md-terrain"></i> <span>Bright Coaching</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Button mobile view to collapse sidebar menu -->
                <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left">
                                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                </button>
                                <span class="clearfix"></span>
                            </div>
                            <form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <%--<input type="text" class="form-control search-bar" placeholder="Type here for search...">--%>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="Usrid" runat="server" />

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!-- Top Bar End -->
            </div>
            <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->

                <div class="left side-menu">
                <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">
                    <div class="user-details">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <%--<img src="images/users/avatar-1.jpg" alt="" class="thumb-md img-circle">--%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                             <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="user-info">
                             <asp:Label ID="lblDt" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--- Divider -->
                    <div id="sidebar-menu">

                        <ul>


                            <li class="has_sub">
                                <a class="waves-effect" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span> User Creation </span><span class="pull-right"><i class="md md-add"></i></span></a>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled" style="">
                                    <li><a href="RegisteredUsers.aspx">Registered Users</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="Create_usrNew.aspx">Create User</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Allow Permission</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Update User</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has_sub">
                                <a class="waves-effect" href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span> Menu </span><span class="pull-right"><i class="md md-add"></i></span></a>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled" style="">
                                    <li><a href="#">Create Branch</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Create Course</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Set Course Fees</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="waves-effect" href="Default.aspx"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span> Logout </span></a>
                            </li>



                        </ul>
                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left Sidebar End --> 
            <div >

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
                <footer class="footer text-right">
                    Powered By Astonish Technology.
                </footer>
            <script>
                var resizefunc = [];
            </script>

       <!-- jQuery  -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/waves.js"></script>
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/jquery-detectmobile/detect.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>


        <!-- CUSTOM JS -->
        <script src="js/jquery.app.js"></script>

        <script src="assets/tagsinput/jquery.tagsinput.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/toggles/toggles.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/timepicker/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/timepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-multi-select/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-multi-select/jquery.quicksearch.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/bootstrap-inputmask/bootstrap-inputmask.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/spinner/spinner.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/select2/select2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                // Tags Input
                jQuery('#tags').tagsInput({ width: 'auto' });

                // Form Toggles
                jQuery('.toggle').toggles({ on: true });

                // Time Picker
                jQuery('#timepicker').timepicker({ defaultTIme: false });
                jQuery('#timepicker2').timepicker({ showMeridian: false });
                jQuery('#timepicker3').timepicker({ minuteStep: 15 });

                // Date Picker
                jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker();
                jQuery('#datepicker-inline').datepicker();
                jQuery('#datepicker-multiple').datepicker({
                    numberOfMonths: 3,
                    showButtonPanel: true
                });
                //colorpicker start

                $('.colorpicker-default').colorpicker({
                    format: 'hex'
                });
                $('.colorpicker-rgba').colorpicker();


                //multiselect start

                $('#my_multi_select1').multiSelect();
                $('#my_multi_select2').multiSelect({
                    selectableOptgroup: true
                });

                $('#my_multi_select3').multiSelect({
                    selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search...'>",
                    selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='form-control search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='search...'>",
                    afterInit: function (ms) {
                        var that = this,
                            $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
                            $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
                            selectableSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
                            selectionSearchString = '#' + that.$container.attr('id') + ' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';

                        that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
                            .on('keydown', function (e) {
                                if (e.which === 40) {
                                    that.$selectableUl.focus();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });

                        that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
                            .on('keydown', function (e) {
                                if (e.which == 40) {
                                    that.$selectionUl.focus();
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                    },
                    afterSelect: function () {
                        this.qs1.cache();
                        this.qs2.cache();
                    },
                    afterDeselect: function () {
                        this.qs1.cache();
                        this.qs2.cache();
                    }
                });

                //spinner start
                $('#spinner1').spinner();
                $('#spinner2').spinner({ disabled: true });
                $('#spinner3').spinner({ value: 0, min: 0, max: 10 });
                $('#spinner4').spinner({ value: 0, step: 5, min: 0, max: 200 });
                //spinner end

                // Select2
                jQuery(".select2").select2({
                    width: '100%'
                });
            });
        </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The master is called in another .aspx page where i have a textbox and a radiobutton. The text box is returning blank value when I am trying to validate or save the record.
 The .aspx is given below

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Admin.master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Create_usrNew.aspx.vb" Inherits="Create_usrNew" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
div class="content-page">
                <!-- Start content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="container">

                    <div class="row">
                            <!-- Basic example -->
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblerr" runat="server" class="fa fa-lock m-r-5" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>--%>
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <%--<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Add User</h3></div>--%>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <%--<form role="form">--%>
                                            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                             <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="">User Name</label>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" placeholder="Create User Name" EnableViewState= "false" Class="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="">Password</label>
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpwd" runat="server" placeholder="Password" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                             <div class="col-md-2">
                                                 <div class="radio radio-info radio-inline">
                                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbtnstate1" runat="server" AutoPostback ="true"
                                                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right"> 

                                                            <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Branch"  Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                                            <asp:ListItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Student" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>

                                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                                   </div>
                                             </div>
                                              <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                                 <div class="form-group">
                                                    <%--<asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Save" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" Onclick="btnsave_Click"/>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" OnClick="btncancel_Click"  />--%>
                                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">Save</asp:LinkButton>
                                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>

                                        <%--</form>--%>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblerr" runat="server" class="fa fa-lock m-r-5" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                    </div><!-- panel-body -->
                                </div> <!-- panel -->
                            </div> <!-- col-->

                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- container -->

                </div> <!-- content -->

            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

the code file is as follows

```
Partial Class Create_usrNew
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cmn As New clsComn
    Dim db As New clsDB
    Dim err As Integer = 0
    Dim usrname As String = ""
    Dim pword As String = ""
    Dim dtcreat As DateTime
    Dim usrtyp As Integer = 0
    Dim selec As Integer = 0
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1))
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
        If (Not IsPostBack) Then
            If Session("uname") <> "" Then
                Session("Moduleid") = 1
                If (db.GetPermission(CInt(Session("usrid")), Session("Moduleid"), 1) = -1) Or (db.GetPermission(CInt(Session("usrid")), Session("Moduleid"), 2) = -1) Or (db.GetPermission(CInt(Session("usrid")), Session("Moduleid"), 3) = -1) Or (db.GetPermission(CInt(Session("usrid")), Session("Moduleid"), 4) = -1) Then

                Else
                    lblerr.Text = "You Are Not Authorised in this Module. Contact Admin"
                    Response.Redirect("~/RegisteredUsers.aspx")
                End If
            Else
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
            End If
            txtpwd.Enabled = False
            clear()
            rdbtnstate1.SelectedValue = 2
        End If

    End Sub

 Private Function verify() As Integer
        Dim err As Integer = 0
        If txtUserName.Text = "" Then
            lblerr.Text = "User Name Cannot be Blank"
            err = -1
        End If
        If rdbtnstate1.SelectedValue = "" Then
            lblerr.Text = "Either of the Selection Has to be Made"
            err = -1
        End If
        Dim sql As String = "Select count(Usrid) from Usertable  where [UsrName]='" + txtUserName.Text + "'"
        If db.SelectData_sql(sql) = 0 Then
        Else
            lblerr.Text = "Username Already Exists"
            err = -1
        End If
        If Session("usrid") = 2 Then
            If rdbtnstate1.SelectedValue = 2 Then
                lblerr.Text = "You Are Not Authorised to Create Branch"
                err = -1
            End If
        End If
        Return err
    End Function
```

Comment: My earlier programs and aspx files are all working fine. Any body helping me out would be sincerely thankful.

Comment: which code do you think is large

Comment: I mean to say on which line, which area do you find error?Its hard to find location of problem

Comment: From where do you call `Verify` function?

Comment: On click of the save button. the verify() is called on the server side

Comment: What I cannot find out is in the aspx file and not in the code behind file. Kindly study the master page and createuser .aspx. There must be some error there itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102997/discussion-between-user1923200-and-hemal).